# Global variable in Objective C IPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, global-variables

I load a few variables in my appdelegate class.  They are declared in my .h file.

I have a `global.h` file that declares the same vars as `extern`, such as:

#### appdelegate.h

```
NSString *DBName;
```

#### global.h

```
extern NSString *DBName;
```

I haven't found the pattern yet, but some of the classes I include the `global.h` but the var is nil.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

#### EDIT:

It looks like the vars that are like:

```
int x;
```

stick and are available,
but the vars that are pointers get lost:

```
NSString *Name;
```

They are all loaded initially from a DB in the appdelegate.

I also tried declaring

```
char Name[30];
```

then assigning it and all is good.

Now what?

Comment: I did look at that already and I couldnt get passed compile errors so gave up. its pretty simple I thought, but the compiler doesnt like it??

Comment: Why wouldn't it be nil? Where do you set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the NSStrings were not retained.  @xianritchie suggested this in the comment above.  I changed the few global strings I have an now all is good.

Thanks all for the help

Answer (score 4):

In a .h:

```
 extern NSString *global;
```

In a .m somewhere:

```
 NSString *global = @"foobar";
```

If you need to set the global at runtime, you'll have to do so in a method somewhere;  say, `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`.

---

Where are you assigning to the global in the NSString case?   And when you do are you retaining the value?  What do you mean by "lost"?

Note that the variable *must not be declared* in a .h;  the extern goes in the .h, the `NSString *global;` *must* be in one and only one .m file.

Comment: Yes I did load the vars in the main app delegate.  they are good there. see the extra comment above

Comment: @Mark Worsnop: Your question says you put the variable in "appdelegate.h", whereas bbum suggested putting it in a "a **.m** file somewhere".

Comment: I did set the values in the .m  but one thing I caught is the "retain" in the above comments.  I do not specifically tell it to retain the values, and maybe that is the problem?  how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of variables are your working with? Are they primitives or objects? If they are primitives, you might think about preprocessor define statements rather than global variables.

If they are objects, you may want to create an implementation of your Global class, and use a Singleton instance to serve and set the variables. Something similar to this

```
@implementation Global
static Global *myGlobal = nil;

+(Global *)sharedInstance
{
    if (myGlobal == nil) {
         myGlobal = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return myGlobal;
}

@end
```

Then you can call the variables using:

```
[[Global sharedInstance] variableName]
```

Comment: Please see the initial message above I added to it.  Looks like the pointers are the problem.  like NSString *Name;

Comment: If you have only a .h file and the NSString defined there, you should create a .m file. You don't have to use the singleton instance, but for these objects, you'll want to define them. I would recommend you add the following for each OBJECT :   Class *variable = nil;. So, for instance, put NSString *DBName = nil; in your .m file.

Comment: I did that but I think I need to "retain" the NSString.  How do I do that?

Comment: Usually this is retained when you initialize the variable. Somewhere, for the string, you are declaring DBName = [[NSString alloc] init];. If you are declaring DBName = [NSString initWithString:(NSString *)aString] or another helper initializer, then the NSString is being assigned an autorelease when it's declared, and it released at the loop. You should be utilizing [[alloc] init] when you initialize the string.